# Spring Enterprise Application Best Practices

Tags: spring, rest, soap

After read the Gordon's article about Best Practices to build Enterprise Application using Spring Framework, I would like to share some ideas about the Service layer.

My architecture represents exactly what Gordon described in this image http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Spring-App-Layers.png

The application is complex, has a heavy business rule and demands to use different resources like Database, SOAP, REST and file handle sometimes in the same use case.

For this scenery that I have described above, I have a Service class that needs to perform SOAP and REST requests and handle some database data. So, I have autowired in my Service class a SOAP and a REST component and the Repository to handle the database stuff.

I'm concerned about if this is the best approach do handle the integration between my Services and the resources like SOAP, REST, Database and etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> So, I have autowired in my Service class a SOAP and a REST component
>   and the Repository to handle the database stuff.

Sounds problematic even though it will work.

Think about the dependency between layers. Service layer will depend on Repository layer (Business logic layer will depend on data layer). Service integration layer (or service communication layer) for incoming requests will depend on the Service layer. But the data layer does not depend on the service layer. Nor the service layer depend on the inbound service invocation layer.

So, remove the SOAP and REST components from the Service class. To the SOAP and REST components, wire the Service instance (i.e. avoid SOAP and REST components wired into the Service, do it in the reverse direction).

This way, when you want to support another integration protocol (say JMS), you do all such work not by modifying your service.

Your data access seems to be fine. I hope your Service accesses the repository via DAOs.

Comment: Thanks @kamal-wickamanayake, looks good to me your concept. Could you show me a code example that exemplifies your idea?

Comment: This is called the layers architectural pattern. It should be clear from the description itself. In case you are new to wiring Spring beans in the way you prefer and particularly doing so with remoting technologies, look at the "Remoting and web web services using Spring" section of the Spring Framework Reference Documentation. It describes how you do so under different conditions.

Comment: I am thinking in realize this integration using Spring Integration. Do you think that is a good approach? Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... I haven't used Spring Integration. So I cannot comment. I checked it and it appears to have some pluses. I would still implement integration with Apache Camel. I might run Camel entirely separately from specific apps. Learning Camel was a problem at the beginning. But soon it became a pretty good and solid integration infrastructure for me. But as said, I don't know what's in Spring Integration clearly. So I cannot jump into conclusions.

Comment: I am taking a look in both technologies Camel and Spring to define the best approach to me. Thanks buddy, I have appreciate your attention

Answer (score 0):

> So, I have autowired in my Service class a SOAP and a REST component
>   and the Repository to handle the database stuff.

Sounds fine. You are using dependency injection, this means they can be easily tested or altered.